# Horizontal ScrollView in Vertical (Dafault) Flatlist

Tags: react-native, scrollview, flatlist

I have a component like there is a FlatList and inside I am using ScrollView to scroll an image horizontally.

```js
<FlatList
    data={feed} 
    renderItem={renderPosts} 
    ListEmptyComponent={<ListEmptyComponent title="We don't have anything to show you!" />} 
    refreshControl={<RefreshControl onRefresh={fetchFeed} refreshing={loading} />}
    />
```

in renderPosts I have something like this

```js
<View>
    ...other content
    <ScrollView horizontal={true}>
        <Image
            ...
            />
    </ScrollView>
    ...other content
</View>
```

So the thing is that I want this image to be scrollable horizontally in a vertical FlatList.

**UPDATE**

I tried the `horizontal={true}` prop value in `ScrollView` but I am having this bug which can be seen in the below link which contains a video. Please check it out.

[Screenrecording](https://imgur.com/a/YBtQKzR)

Answer (score 0):

> **horizontal** - When true, the scroll view's children are arranged horizontally in a row instead of vertically in a column.

From React Native docs https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#horizontal

```js
<View>
    ...other content
    <ScrollView horizontal={true}> // <-- add the horizontal prop
        <Image
            ...
            />
    </ScrollView>
    ...other content
</View>
```

Comment: @DarshanJaviya some troubles in your layout, I create minimal code https://snack.expo.dev/@vasylnahuliak/76496640 and it's work. Please provide full information about your layout structure and create Expo Snack. Thanks for video

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am not able to reproduce it in snack but that same bug is still in my code. https://snack.expo.dev/@jdarshan1210/1edaf9 please check this out, I have tried my best to show you how my layout is.

Comment: Try remove `TouchableNativeFeedback`. You can use `onPress` and `onLongPress` on `ScrollView` instead.

Comment: well ScrollView does not have onPress and onLongPress but the thing I did and it resolved my issue is that I wrapped the TouchableNativeFeedback inside the scrollview. That's it and it solved my problem. Thank you @VasylNahuliak for your help